# How can I get rid of these artifacts in blender internal render?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

[Why do these weird artifacts appear in the render (blender internal) and how can I get rid of them, without switching to cycles? No double faces or intersecting geometry in the scene... The artifacts occur when a mesh is in front of a plane with a transparent image.

[image: artifacts around mesh in front of "transparent" plane]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEpuB.png)

Comment: it should be an aplha blending issue, but it may depend either on the "image with transparency" or on some material setting... or both! having the file coudl help to find this particular issue.

Comment: thanks for the input! I checked out the materials and alpha channels of the transparent images, they looked ok. Found a solution though! By changing the render "Anti-aliasing" to "Full Sample" the artifacts were removed.

Answer (score 1):

Transparent objects and solid objects are rendered in two different steps during the render pipeline.

If you compare the render pass of solid color with the z-transparent one, you'll notice that the alpha channels do not match perfectly.

Combining the solid and transparent layers, you'll get some differences along the anti-aliased edges.

To solve this issue without increasing the render size, you can toggle transparency in the solid material (the character).

Doing so, Blender Internal will render the whole scene in a single pass.

Here you can find a similar example:

[How can I make transparency act as expected with the internal renderer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43778/how-can-i-make-transparency-act-as-expected-with-the-internal-renderer/43938#43938)

Answer (score -1):

By changing the setting for render "Anti-aliasing" to "Full Sample" the artifacts were removed.

[image]

Comment: This was auto-flagged as potentially low quality. You might want to add an image showing the options etc.

Comment: this doesn't make sense. Full sample is only used for special compositing cases.