# How can I make transparency act as expected with the internal renderer?

Tags: texturing, transparency, artifacts

Seems like a z-buffer issue.

Everything seems fine in the material preview, but in the render the sky (or transparency, if no sky) "bleeds" a pixel or two between the intersecting part (intersecting in the 2d render, not 3d) transparent textured geometry and any geometry behind it. Hope this makes some sense:

[image]

Material/texture settings are as follows:
[image]

[image]

Changing transparency mode of the Texture from Straight to Premultiplied doesn't fix it.

blend can be found here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8pm58kHwzU3M3hUZmdFdUhTdDg

The texture file separately can be found here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/19cvI.jpg
Tried a different texture file from cgtextures with no difference.

Comment: is this the same question as http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43015/blender-transparent-texture-rendering-artifact-internal-renderer ?

Comment: It is accessible. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8pm58kHwzU3M3hUZmdFdUhTdDg/view?usp=sharing If something is wrong, google is to blame. I tried Pasteall.org first but it would never finish uploading. THey never implemented a status bar so I don't know if it's extremely slow or just bugged out.  PS. sorry for double post, so much has happened I had forgot I had asked this before. in any case, now I have the blend and texture file uploaded.

Comment: A random guess without looking, toggle Pre-multiplied Alpha on the texture/material. I had some contrasting outline problems fixed that way.

Comment: tried that.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Toggle transparency in the branches material

[image: Branch material]

It seems that there is some issue in the render pipeline, due to the anti-aliasing of the smaller parts.

If you compare the render pass of solid color with the z-transparent one, you'll notice that the alpha channels do not match perfectly.

[image: render pass solid]

[image: render pass z-transparence]

[image: differences]

### EDIT

Actually is not a bug, but a limit of the approximation instead.

As @Jerryno and @HalfKiloByte suggest, if you used more accurate algorithms and less approximation, you would avoid subpixel issues in the smaller parts.

I've increased the render resolution (10 times) to better evaluate the steps and the final result.

You'll notice the two passes (solid and transparent) here:

[image: Rendering in progress]

In the final render there are no pixels around the branches:

[image: Rendering in progress 2]

Comment: So you think it's a bug? I get that antialiasing has something to do with it, but even if it was turned off, if Blender properly used the depth buffer for Z-Transparency, wouldn't what really is behind the pixel be drawn, not something which is behind everyting else in the scene and probably also in the depth buffer?

Comment: @LeoErvin I've edited the answer to better explain the process. Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

The **main problem** is anti-aliasing the alpha borders of the leaves. You should **enable *Full Sample*** in the Render options for best quality. This will render correctly:

[image]

Other problem for best quality might be the transparent texture itself. There is no color bleed over the transparent edge. There is black background over the transparent pixels.
On the leafs texture sampling and filtering happens. And the transparent border get's blurred and the black leaks into the leafs. The image without alpha channel should look like the right one:

[image]

Make sure when you are exporting the whole rgb channels are exported and not clipped with the alpha channel.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Hope this Helps, better then words an image!]
Hope this Helps, better then words an image!
And what's more there is a [blend file HERE](https://mega.nz/#!mNMG3SiY!1S2CzOZPbDIGQBRJBges4RTj0aV7NFj4fJ8KR2Emxvw) for your reference
good luck cheers! Be sure to click on download through your browers
so you don't have to install the mega site's software.

PS : Do study the image of the leaf I have included it's been processed
with photoshop so that the edges of the leaf's color are also copied to
make buffers for error.

Comment: Could you please explain what the Stencil option does here? It's usually used as a mask for two texture  images. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok found the explaination on blender manual here is the link ...http://www.blender.org/manual/render/blender_render/textures/influence/material.html

Comment: @LeoErvin the option is to tell the image is a mask for the next image in the texture stack, and it does not fix the issue. It makes it even worse..

Comment: Yeah, that's not a solution Sorry, hawkenfox.

Comment: I use GIMP. But why should I worry about extending the edge colors if I use alpha channel in multiply mode? My understanding of the issue is if that was to blame, my texture image would need to have "feathered edges" for that to be the case, or semitransparent pixels on the edges of the leaves, to explain it in another way. But they don't. If there's more to the "background color" of images with alpha channel and how it affects 3d renders, please include that in an answer.

Comment: You should read about this and why png isn't a very good format to use as alpha channel is just white or black . Basically I think what the poster is saying is that png only offer black or white and no inbetween for it's alpha channel which can cause problems in 3d software interpretation of the alphas. http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/10302/messy-alpha-problem-white-around-edges.html ... as for extending the edge colors it's an assurance when you are using the PNG format ... they are famous for causing issue with the alpha they produced ...

Comment: No difference. http://i.imgur.com/CaoAdai.png

Comment: @LeoErvin Pls see my answer and check Full Sample.

Comment: Problem is with geometry that has texture with alpha channel. Branches in this example is a mix of solid geometry with no alpha channel and geometry which has the tips of these branches with the leaves on them with alpha channel. Problem is with the latter. I'm afraid telling that Blender has problems in rendering this tells nothing. I already know that hence why I'm here. I want to know why and how to fix it. Checking full sampleor using other transparency mode like raytracing is not much of a solution than a workaround, a render-heavy ones too. Appreciated,but can't accept as answer.

Comment: This isn't about not wanting to give off points.  Questions shouldn't be address but answered. Again, you saying some people think this is a bug doesn't tell anything. Also, what you described is not a problem with Z-Transparency. That's a general issue with 3d (OpenGL, DirectX when *not* using Z-Transparency.

Answer (score 0):

This is a strange phantom issue that I will never learn how to solve. It totally depends on what you want to do with the image. There is the case when the branch outlines go away, but a bright outline will appear when you switch from Sky color to Transparent background.

I usually play with these and get different results:

- Render Options > Shading > Alpha: Sky or Transparent
- Render Options > Anti-Aliasing (Oversampling): On or Off
- Material > Transparency mode: Z-transparency or Raytrace
- Texture > Alpha mode: Straight or Premultiplied

Your case is easily solved by setting the material transparency to "Raytrace".

[image]

This image was made with:

- Render Options > Shading > Alpha: Sky
- Render Options > Anti-Aliasing (Oversampling): On
- Material > Transparency mode: Raytrace
- Texture > Alpha mode: Straight

But you don't want to set it to transparent background without playing with the other settings.

Comment: Z-transparency uses the depth buffer as far as I know, I don't see why it would be necessary to use Raytracing transparency which can substantially increase render time just to not have this issue.  This is a workaround and not for every situation sadly. But thanks for posting.